# mean.io fails to listen on localhost:3000 following steps in documentation

Tags: mean.io

mean.io fails to listen on `localhost:3000` following steps in documentation

It stops with the messages below:

```
C:\meanio\myapp>node server.js
for real!
forking  0
forking  1
forking  2
forking  3
```

I followed steps from learn.mean.io:

It was working in version

```
{
  "name": "mean",
  "description": "MEAN.io: A fullstack JavaScript framework powered by MongoDB, ExpressJS, AngularJS, NodeJS.",
  "version": "0.5.5",
  "private": false,
  "author": "Linnovate <mean@linnovate.net>",
  "contributors": "https://github.com/linnovate/mean/graphs/contributors",
  "mean": "0.5.5",
```

Now I am trying with version

```
{
  "name": "mean",
  "description": "MEAN.io: A fullstack JavaScript framework powered by MongoDB, ExpressJS, AngularJS, NodeJS.",
  "version": "0.6.1",
  "private": false,
  "author": "Linnovate <mean@linnovate.net>",
  "contributors": "https://github.com/linnovate/mean/graphs/contributors",
  "mean": "0.6.1",
```

If any body know why it is getting stuck, please let me know.

Comment: Ahh, I'll redact my comment. Mean.IO is not bad. I just think you'll do yourself a big favour if you also have a look at some of the other mean-stacks. Search for mean generators at [yeoman](http://yeoman.io) and try the top ones out, if you have the time.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `npm test` start your dev server with `gulp`